# How to save a queryset?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I would like to know how I can save my queryset in the database:

```
def data_min(self):
        qs1 = Csr.objects.values_list('value_base')
        qs2 = Modelb.objects.filter(Q(limit_a__gte=qs1) & (Q(limit_b__lte=qs1))).distinct().values_list('limit_b')
        qs3 = qs2[0]
        return qs3
```

This function returns me:

```
<QuerySet [(Decimal('133.22'),)]>
```

Now my question is how I keep it in my Model in the field "bdata_superior":

```
class Csr(models.Model):
tarifa_cobro = models.ForeignKey(Tarifa_Sem, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
value_base = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
bdata_superior = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
data_inferior = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)

class Modelb(models.Model):
    limit_a = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    limit_b = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
```

The problem is that when I save it, I get the following error:

```
conversion from method to Decimal is not supported

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.bdata_superior = self.data_min
        super (Crs, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: This Stack Overflow site is an English-only site.  For other languages, visit the other stack overflow sites, such as `https://es.stackoverflow.com/`

Comment: Can you please elaborate the question?

Comment: You should save Model. `Csr.objects.create(tarifa_cobro_id=1, bdata_superior=1.0, data_inferior=2.0)`

Comment: Please share `Modelb` definition.  And do you want to connect it to the record or a field value within the record?

Comment: I want to overwrite the save method to save it in the field "bdata_superior" of the class Crs

Comment: qs2 = Modelb.objects.filter(Q(limit_a__gte=qs1) & Q(limit_b__lte=qs1)).distinct().values_list('limit_b')

Comment: removed the extra braces

Comment: I keep giving the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I update the response to this thread.

First update my qs2, the error showed it to me because I was trying to save the queryset, then a tuple, to access the value of my queryset, just add the flat = True parameter, within the values_list () method and access the first value of my tuple in the position [0]

Here is my updated function

```
def data_min(self):
    qs1 = Csr.objects.values_list('base_gravada')
    qs2 = Modelb.objects.filter
    (Q(limit_a__gte=qs1) & 
     Q(limit_b__lte=qs1))
     .distinct().values_list('limit_b', flat=True)[0]
```

and the save method

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.bdata_superior = self.data_min()
    super (Calculadora_isr, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Thank you so much for everything @harshil9968

Answer (score 0):

call the `data_min` function and then save, the return value to `self.bdata_superior`, you're presently assigning the function to `self.bdata_superior`

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.bdata_superior = self.data_min()
        super (Crs, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I just tested what you said and now I get the error: Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value: 
argument must be a sequence of length 3

Comment: can you put the stack trace? to explain a little more, like from which function it's arising?